# tensorflow - same program on different computers allocate different GPU memory

Tags: python, tensorflow

ubuntu 16.04, python 2.7.12, tensorflow 1.10.1 (gpu version), cuda 9.0, cudnn 7.2

I have built and trained a CNN model, and now I am using a while loop to repeatedly let my model make predictions.

In order to limit the memory usage, I am using the following code to create my classifier:

```
import tensorflow as tf

session_config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False)
session_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True 
run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig().replace(session_config=session_config)


classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn = my_model_fn, 
    model_dir = my_trained_model_dir,
    config = run_config,
    params={}
```

)

And I call `classifier.predict(my_input_fn)` in a `while` loop to repeatedly make predictions.

**Issue:**

I am running my codes on two computers, both with the same software environment as I listed above.

However, the two computers have different GPUs:

Computer A: 1050 2G

Computer B: 1070 8G

My code works well on both computer.

**However, when I use `nvidia-smi` to check the GPU memory allocation, I found that my code will allocate 1.4G GPU memory on Computer A, while it becomes 3.6G on Computer B.**

**So, Why would this happen?**

**I think `session_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True` tells the program to allocate as much as it needs. Computer A has proved that 1.4G is enough, then why would the same code allocate 3.6G on Computer B?**

Comment: It might be worth it to add a `cuda` tag to this since it seems likely to me that the `cuda` or `cudnn` backend would have things to say about memory allocation based on the GPU you have available. I don't know much about the details of that unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

It may be that 1.4gb is actually not enough, and some of the required memory is swapped into main memory. Video cards drivers do that.